# Class of compact cardinals implies every accessible category is co-wellpowered

Tags: category-theory, large-cardinals, accessible-categories

As the title says, I'm looking for the reference that the existence of a class of compact cardinals implies every accessible category is co-wellpowered. It has been stated in Adamek-Rosicky (*Locally presentable and accessible categories*) that this is proved in Makkai-Paré (*Accessible categories: the foundations of categorical model theory*), but I couldn't find the proof anywhere. Sorry if this sounds lazy but I don't have a physical copy of the latter book, only a scan which doesn't have OCR so I can't search text.

I've found a proof that powerful images of accessible functors are accessible under the stated assumption, so does co-wellpoweredness follow from this by some argument which I can't see? I'd love a hint in that case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is strange because in my copy of Makkai-Paré, there is a reference to 6.2.11 on page 63 but there is no 6.2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Accessible categories: the foundations of categorical model theory* (Makkai, Paré), we find the following:

(part of) **Theorem 6.3.8.** If there are arbitrarily large compact cardinals, then colimits are uniformly detectable in every accessible category.

**Proposition 6.2.2.** If pushouts are detectable in an accessible category, then it is co-well-powered.

Detectable and uniformly detectable colimits are defined in 6.2. If colimits are uniformly detectable, then colimits are detectable. What you are looking for follows.